# to mince vs to mince up

Tags: meaning-in-context, emphasis

I was reading a Lucky Luke comic where one of the speech balloons says:

> Joe! Mince me up another cow!

Since *mince up* was new to me I looked for it in a dictionary. However, I was able to find only *mince* that as a verb means:

> to cut food into very small pieces

So far so good, this makes sense, but what's with the **up**? It doesn't seem to be phrasal verb so here are my quesions:

- Would it be correct to assume that adding **up** is some kind of an emphasis?
- What are the *exact* rules for this?
- Are there any other prepositions that can be used in this way?
- What is the grammatical term for it so I can read more about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The particle "up" is very common to indicate "completion". It forms separable phrasal verbs with many verbs.  Another related sense of phrasal verbs with "up" is "into small pieces".  Because if you take a cutting process to completion, you make small pieces. So we have

> chew up, cut up, tear up, slice up and (perhaps) blow up.

The particle "up" is productive in this sense, which means that you can create new phrasal verbs that aren't in the dictionary.  If you have a verb that means "break or cut" (in some way) you can add "up" to mean "break or cut completely into small pieces".

Of course "mince" is such a verb, so you can form a phrasal verb "mince up" to mean "completely mince into small pieces".  And the exaggeration of "mince up another cow" is what makes this funny.

You can add other prepositions but each one is rather idiomatic, and it is sometimes difficult to guess the effect of a particular preposition.  As it is idiomatic, the exact rules are not easy to state, instead there are just a lot of special cases.

The grammatical term is "phrasal verb"  Here is a list https://www.really-learn-english.com/phrasal-verbs-with-up.html